# update multiple "B" sobject records with newly create "A" sobject record Id in lwc using uiRecordApi

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

i am trying to update the `B object` records with newly created `A object`  record Id by using this approach [in line multiple rows edit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.data_table_inline_edit). i am able to created `A object` record successfully. then i build the array of object `B object` Record Inputs. 
but when i do `promise.all` of promises it's failed and record are not updated. but promise jump 2 outer error with message `promise is not defined` did i miss any thing please hemp to figure out the issue.

```
import {createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import A_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/A__c';
import ACTION_A_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/A__c.Action_A__c';
import B_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/B__c.Id';
import B_A_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/B__c.B_A__c';

    createArecordaction(event){
            const fields = {};
            fields[ACTION_A_FIELD .fieldApiName] = this.action;
            const ARecordInput = { apiName: A_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
            createRecord(ARecordInput )
                .then(aRecord => {
                    this.aRecordId = aRecord.id;
                    const brecordsinputs = this.Selectedbrecords.map(incb => {
                        let fields = {};
                        fields[B_ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = incassociate;
                        fields[B_A_FIELD.fieldApiName] = nodRecord.id;
                        fields = Object.assign({}, fields);
                        return { fields };
                    });
                    console.log('bassociaterecs :', brecordsinputs ); //bassociaterecs - [proxy ] in console JSON.stringify gives "[{"fields":{"Id":"a1gr0000000cI7aAAE","B_A__c":"a1or00000019Pw6AAE"}}]" 
                    const promises = brecordsinputs .map(AssbrecordInput => createRecord(AssrecordInput)); //0: Promise {<pending>} because of one record it gives one promise with pending state then jump 2 outer error with error message "promise is not defined"
                    promise.all(promises).then((assocs)=>{
                        console.log('assocs', assocs);
                        this.closeModal();

                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Error while updating B records',
                                message: error.body.message,
                                variant: 'error'
                            })
                        );
                    });

                })
                .catch(error => { // code flow jump here with 'promise is not defined' message
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error while creating A record', 
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                });

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Promise`, not `promise`. JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe.

Comment: TFW you see @sfdcfox appear in the "Low Quality Posts" queue... great answer, though

Comment: good catch, saved my day